# Java socket writeByte and newline

Tags: java, sockets, newline, outputstream

I got a question for something I can't seem to understand.

If I use the snippet:

```
DataOutputStream dataoutput = new DataOutputStream(Socket.getOutputStream());

dataoutput.writeBytes(diagnostics);
dataoutput.flush();
```

The output:diagnostics that is sent from server to client hangs, where even using .flush() will not help.  Only closing the socket will release the data packet.

However, if I add a newline character:

```
dataoutput.writeBytes(diagnostics+"\n");
```

it works perfectly.  And if you duplicate the code,

```
dataoutput.writeBytes(diagnostics);
dataoutput.writeBytes(diagnostics);
```

You get the same output as the one with the /newline without duplicate data.  Why?

EDIT: Client-side.

```
incoming = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
response = incoming.readLine();
```

Comment: How would we know?  You didn't even tell us about what type dataoutput is...

Comment: My guess is that there is a new line missing in your output and the reader expects a new line (and hangs waiting for it)

Comment: @fstd It's most likely a DataOutputStream. In which case writeBytes is a bit odd in the fact that it does not guarantee all bytes are pushed to the server, you should do a flush() after each writeBytes to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, it was a DataOutputStream.  I'm just a bit confused why flush() doesn't work, or why duplicating the code works as well.

Comment: Could you post the snipet of the client code you are using to read the data? It may help

Comment: Do you have tcpnodelay on for the socket options?  Might be getting caught in the network buffer.  Have you tried looking at the packet level with something like Wireshark? The flush() is for the buffered output stream, it has no effect on the Socket, and is probably why it works correctly when you duplicate the code.  Your filling the network buffer with enough data to fill the packet.

Comment: @LexWebb DataOutputStream is not buffered  and does not require flushing. Your statement about the writeBytes() method is baseless.

Comment: @Dalmity What you describe is impossible, particularly the part of about not getting the duplication. I therefore have to question your observations. However if you are reading with a BufferedReader you should certainly be writing with a BufferedWriter. Don't forget to flush it when necessary, as that is buffered, unlike DataOutputStream, which isn't, and doesn't, contrary to several statements here.

Answer (score 0):

Like the good lads puts in the comment you should use a flush to force send the payload to destination of the stream. But if that isn't working i suggest to try the following :

```
    DataOutputStream dataoutput = new DataOutputStream(System.out);

    dataoutput.writeBytes(diagnostics);
    dataoutput.flush();
```

So now the destination will be the "local" console. and no remote connection is between the source and the destination of the stream, perhaps you can try for yourself if anything is working properly "locally" (and focus in the DataOutputStream behaviour) and then start to tackle the remote streaming process.

Is it not to much, but hope it helps a little!

Greetings!!

Comment: Ey, at least i brought an idea.. if you downvote at least tell why and be more constructive.